# Why doesn't Google like my PHP script?

Tags: php, http

I am trying to connect to http://google.com/ and receive their home page with the following code:

```
$sock=stream_socket_client("tcp://google.com:80");

fwrite($sock,"GET / HTTP 1/1\r\n");
fwrite($sock,"Host: google.com\r\n");
fwrite($sock,"User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0\r\n");
fwrite($sock,"Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n");
fwrite($sock,"Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\n");
fwrite($sock,"Connection: close\r\n");
fwrite($sock,"Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n");
```

But this is Google's "HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request" reply:

```
HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 925
Date: Mon, 03 Feb 2014 04:06:53 GMT
Server: GFE/2.0
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: On hindsight, the fact that you're trying `1.1` and getting `1.0` is an obvious clue - but then you know what they say about hindsight. I'm just putting this in here to remind myself about these sorts of errors. :)

Comment: I noticed that too but assumed Google was catering for everybody with older browsers...  But you're right, it was a clue.

Answer (score 2):

The first line should be:

```
fwrite($sock,"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                        ^ ^
```

Comment: I’m embarrassed now...  Thanks for the correction! :)